# Adding Traefik StripPrefix middleware to docker-compose labels results in 504

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, middleware, traefik

I have developed several docker-ized full-stack web applications that I am trying to route requests to using Traefik. I want to take advantage of the dynamic configuration via docker-compose labels.  I would like to apply the stripPrefix middleware option so I can use the same application routing as if each app were served at the root.  However, once these rules are applied it results in a 504 Gateway Timeout response.

Here's my set up:

- Traefik 2.0.1
- Docker 19.03.2, Compose 1.24.1
- NGINX:latest images
- A `global` docker network on which the Traefik container runs
- Multiple multi-container applications, each of which includes an NGINX web server
- All applications have their own `local` networks and the NGINX containers are also on the `global` network.
- Each application is configured to be listening at `/`

Here is the `docker-compose.yml` definition for the offending NGINX container:

```
nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        container_name: "mps_nginx"
        volumes:
        - ./nginx/confs/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/default.conf
        - ./static:/www/static
        restart: "always"
        labels:
            - traefik.http.routers.mps.rule=Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/mps`)
            - traefik.http.middlewares.strip-mps.stripprefix.prefixes=/mps
            - traefik.http.routers.mps.middlewares=strip-mps@docker
        networks:
        - default
        - mps
```

The aggravating part is, when I comment out the `middlewares` labels, it runs just fine but cannot find a matching URL pattern.

Prior to this I tested my approach using the `whoami` container that is defined in the [Traefik Quickstart Tutorial](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guides/docker-compose/basic-example/):

```
# Test service to make sure our local docker-compose network functions
  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/whoami`)
      - traefik.http.middlewares.strip-who.stripprefix.prefixes=/whoami
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.middlewares=strip-who@docker
```

A request to `http://localhost/whoami` returns (among other things)
`GET / HTTP/1.1`.

This is exactly how I expected my routing approaches to work for all my other applications.  The Traefik dashboard shows green all around for every middleware I register and yet all I see is 504 errors.

If anyone has any clues I would sincerely appreciate it.

Answer (score 8):

#### To summarize my solution to a similar problem

```
  my-service:
    image: some/image
    ports: # no need to expose port, just to show that service listens on 8090
      - target: 8090
        published: 8091
        mode: host
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myservice-router.rule=PathPrefix(`/myservice/`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myservice-router.service=my-service"
      - "traefik.http.services.myservice-service.loadbalancer.server.port=8090"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.myservice-strip.stripprefix.prefixes=/myservice"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.myservice-strip.stripprefix.forceslash=false"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myservice-router.middlewares=myservice-strip"
```

##### Now details

Routing rule

... redirect all calls thats path starts with **/myservice/**

```
- "traefik.http.routers.myservice-router.rule=PathPrefix(`/myservice/`)"
```

... to service **my-service**

```
- "traefik.http.routers.myservice-router.service=my-service"``
```

... to port 8090

```
- "traefik.http.services.myservice-service.loadbalancer.server.port=8090"
```

... and uses **myservice-strip** middleware

```
- "traefik.http.routers.myservice-router.middlewares=myservice-strip"
```

... this middleware will strip **/myservice** from path

```
- "traefik.http.middlewares.myservice-strip.stripprefix.prefixes=/myservice"
```

... and **will not** add trailing slash (/) if path becomes an empty string

```
- "traefik.http.middlewares.myservice-strip.stripprefix.forceslash=false"
```

Comment: I have been trying this set up for 2 days and finally after referring your code was finally able to make it work! Thanks a ton for posting this! Was going mad!
Just could not figure out why the backend was not redirecting to my other container

Comment: ty for you answer! This solve this https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/behind-a-proxy/?h=trae#proxy-with-a-stripped-path-prefix

Answer (score 1):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/5159) with prefix without ending with '/'. 
Test your config like this:

```
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`localhost`) && (PathPrefix(`//whoami/`) || PathPrefix(`/portainer`))"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.strip-who.stripprefix.prefixes=/whoami"
```

Comment: is      **|| PathPrefix(`/portainer`)** necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that was solved with the addition of

`- "traefik.http.middlewares.strip-who.stripprefix.forceslash=true"`

It makes sure the strip prefix doesn't also remove the forward slash.

You can read more about the `forceslash` documentation  https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/stripprefix/